# Using useFetch doesn't populate the data in the webpage although under network tab the api call succeeds, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am using nuxt3. I don't understand why the below code doesn't work when I use `useFetch` instead of `$fetch`. When I `useFetch`, the network tab shows the data is fetched properly, but the elements are not populated in the webpage. Bow when I use `$fetch`, everything is populated properly. What could be the reason for this?

I am not using `onMounted()` because I want to keep the benefits of nuxt and SSR when it comes to SEO. So if I am not mistaken, if I use `onMounted` and reactive components like `ref` it will mostly load when it viewed from the browser. Let me know if I am wrong in this aspect.

```
import FooterOne from "../Common/FooterOne.vue";
import PageTitle from "../Common/PageTitle.vue";
import Pagination from "../Common/Pagination.vue";
import CourseBar from "./CourseBar.vue";
import Header from "../Common/Header.vue";

const props = defineProps(['category', 'order'])
const { data: courses } = await useFetch("/api/courses", {
   query: {
      sort: props.order ? props.order : 'asc'
   }
})
let state = reactive({courses})
onMounted(() => {
   if(props.category) {
      for (let i=0; i <= courses.length; i++) {
         const el = courses[i]
         if (props.category == el.category) {
            state.courses.push(el)
         }
      }
   }
})
watchEffect(() => {
   state.courses = courses
   for (let i=0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      const el = courses[i]
      if (props.category == el.category) {
         state.courses.push(el)
      }
   }
})
</script>


<template>
   <div>
      <!-- header-area-start -->
      <Header />
      <!-- header-area-end -->

      <!-- PageTitle-area-start -->
      <PageTitle pageTitle="Courses" pageSubTitle="Courses" />
      <!-- PageTitle-area-end -->

      <!-- course-bar-area-start -->
      <CourseBar />
      <!-- course-bar-area-end -->

      <!-- course-area-start -->
      <section class="course-content-area pb-90">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-10">
               <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-8">
                  <ShopSidebar />
               </div>
               <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                  <div class="row pb-25">
                     <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6" v-for="item in state.courses" :key="item.id">
                        <div class="course-wrapper-2 mb-30">
                           <div class="student-course-img">
                              <img :src="item.featuredImage ? item.featuredImage.url : '/img/course/course-01.jpg'" :alt="item.featuredImage ? item.featuredImage.name : 'courde-img'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="course-cart">
                              <div class="course-info-wrapper">
                                 <div class="cart-info-body">
                                    <span class="category-color category-color-3">
                                       <NuxtLink to="/courses">{{ item.category }}</NuxtLink>
                                    </span>
                                    <NuxtLink :to="`/course-details/${item.id}`">
                                       <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
                                    </NuxtLink>
                                    <div class="cart-lavel">
                                       <h5>Level <span>Beginner</span></h5>
                                       <p>{{ item.tagline }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info-cart-text">
                                       <ul>
                                          <li v-for="itemTwo, index in item.features" :key="index"><i
                                                class="far fa-check"></i>{{ itemTwo }}</li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="course-action">
                                       <NuxtLink :to="`/course-details/${item.id}`" class="view-details-btn">
                                          View Details</NuxtLink>
                                       <button class="wishlist-btn"><i class="flaticon-like"></i></button>
                                       <NuxtLink :to="`/course-details/${item.id}`" class="c-share-btn"><i
                                             class="flaticon-previous"></i></NuxtLink>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="student-course-footer">
                              <div class="student-course-linkter">
                                 <div class="course-lessons">
                                    <i class="flaticon-tv"></i>
                                    <span class="ms-2">{{ item.modules }}</span>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="portfolio-price">
                                    <span>{{ item.cost ? '₹' + item.cost : '' }}</span>
                                    <!-- <del>{{ item.priceOld }}</del> -->
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="student-course-text">
                                 <h3>
                                    <NuxtLink :to="`/course-details/${item.id}`">{{ item.title }}</NuxtLink>
                                 </h3>
                              </div>
                              <!-- <div class="portfolio-user">
                                 <div class="user-icon">
                                    <NuxtLink to="/instructor"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>{{ item.tutor }}
                                    </NuxtLink>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="course-icon">
                                    <i :class="item.productRating1"></i>
                                    <i :class="item.productRating2"></i>
                                    <i :class="item.productRating3"></i>
                                    <i :class="item.productRating4"></i>
                                    <i :class="item.productRating5"></i>
                                    <span>{{ item.rating }}</span>
                                 </div>
                              </div> -->
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <Pagination />
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <!-- course-area-end -->

      <!-- Footer-area-start -->
      <FooterOne />
      <!-- Footer-area-end -->

   </div>

</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is `$fetch` gets the data and loads the page if done using `SSR` but downloads it in `async` for `CSR`. `useFetch` always returns a promise. That would explain why this is happening for me. I am unsure if my understanding is correct though.